# Android:voice recording with timer

Tags: android, avaudiorecorder

i am creating media recorder demo application. for that i have take two button start and stop.
i want to display timer when click on start button and want to stop on stop button.

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution can be based on these classes:

```
public static class TimeCounter{
    private long startTime;

    public TimeCounter(){
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public long countTime(){
        return new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    }
}

public class TimeCounterTask extends AsyncTask<TimeCounter, Long, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(TimeCounter... params) {
        TimeCounter tc = params[0];
        while(true){
            publishProgress(new Long(tc.countTime()));
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        long millis = values[0].longValue();
        int minutes = (int) ((millis / 1000) / 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((millis / 1000) % 60);
        String s = String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
                minutes, seconds);
        timerText.setText(s);
    }

}
```

- in start button handler create new TimerCounterTask and execute it this new TimerCounter() parameter
- in stop button handler stop current task
- timerText is TextView for display timer

Comment: publishProgress calls before sleep, so it should begin from 00:00. Where are problem?